# If you expose a RSS feed on the internet will you need to do any setup on the reverse proxy for it?

Tags: proxy, rss, reverse

If you expose a RSS feed on the internet will you need to do any setup on the reverse proxy for it? We have an RSS feed that we would like to feed to the website twitterfeed.com; however the RSS feed is on a server that is behind a company firewall. Would anything need to be setup on the reverse proxy as well as potentially the external internet service provider's reverse proxy due to html messages coming to the company's server; or does RSS just push data and do not have to cater for any handshaking messages?

Answer (score 0):

No, by *default* RSS is just like any other HTTP-consumed resourced: clients will issues requests to get it and then the server will respond to that request by serving it. In other words; yes, you'll need to setup things on your reverse proxy so that twitterfeed or any other service an access the feed.